# Whats the difference between the Instance Variables and the win variable I define and the play_game method. Why is there no self too?

Tags: python, class, oop

```
from random import randint


class Card:
    suits = ["spades", "hearts", "diamonds", "clubs"]

    values = [None, None, "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8",
              "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"]

    def __init__(self, v, s):
        """suit + value are ints"""
        self.value = v
        self.suit = s

    def __gt__(self, c2):
        if self.value > c2.value:
            return True
        if self.value == c2.value:
            if self.suit > c2.suit:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        return False

    def __repr__(self):
        v = self.values[self.value] + " of " + self.suits[self.suit]
        return v


class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.wins = 0
        self.card = None
        self.name = name


class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        for i in range(2, 15):
            for j in range(4):
                self.cards.append(Card(i, j))
        self.random_cards = []
        for x in range(len(self.cards)):
            self.x = randint(0, len(self.cards) - 1)
            self.random_cards.append(self.cards[self.x])
            self.cards.pop(self.x)

    def rm_card(self):
        if len(self.random_cards) == 0:
            return
        return self.random_cards.pop()


class Game:
    def __init__(self):

        name1 = input("p1 name ")
        name2 = input("p2 name ")
        self.deck = Deck()
        self.p1 = Player(name1)
        self.p2 = Player(name2)

    def wins(self, winner):
        w = "{} wins this round"
        w = w.format(winner)
        print(w)

    def draw(self, p1n, p1c, p2n, p2c):
        d = "{} drew {} {} drew {}"
        d = d.format(p1n, p1c, p2n, p2c)
        print(d)

    def play_game(self):
        cards = self.deck.random_cards
        print("beginning War!")
        while len(cards) >= 2:
            m = "q to quit. Any key to play:"
            response = input(m)
            if response == 'q':
                break
            p1c = self.deck.rm_card()
            p2c = self.deck.rm_card()
            p1n = self.p1.name
            p2n = self.p2.name
            self.draw(p1n, p1c, p2n, p2c)
            if p1c.__gt__(p2c):
                self.p1.wins += 1
                self.wins(p1n)
            else:
                self.p2.wins += 1
                self.wins(p2n)
        win = self.winner(self.p1, self.p2)
        if win == "It was a tie!":
            print("It was a tie!")
        else:
            print("War is over.{} wins".format(win))

    def winner(self, p1, p2):
        if p1.wins > p2.wins:
            return p1.name
        if p1.wins < p2.wins:
            return p2.name
        return "It was a tie!"


game = Game()
game.play_game()
```

Instance Variables get defined in the init method, so they can get initialized. But I couldnt define the win (class Game, play_game method) variable in it, since I didnt have all the arguments in the init method yet. So whats the difference between the win variable and the instance Variables and why dont I use a self there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you don't use 'self' for win is because it only needs to exist inside the method it was created in, whereas the other variables(i.e. things that are defined outside of the method) have to exhist in more than one function always (the **init** and also in whatever function you implement those values). With the win variable it is only needed in your play_game() method, so it  doesn't need self.

Answer (score -1):

> Instance Variables get defined in the init method, so they can get initialized.

They are **attributes**, getting initialised and not variables. There is a difference.

> So whats the difference between the win variable and the instance Variables

The difference is that once you initialise the attributes, you give them an initial value so that you can change them later on.

> why dont I use a self there?

You do not need to use self when calling the method because you are telling - `self.winner(args)`. So it is the same as `winner(self,args)`